# Using SVG masks or custom-shaped masks in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg

I am trying to get custom shaped masks work in IE. I am able to achieve this in other browsers using SVG masks. For Firefox, I'm using the CSS property clip-path like clip-path: url(circle_ff.svg#c1); and for Safari, I'm specifying the sag mask image using the -webkit-mask-image css property like this: -webkit-mask-image: url(circle.svg);

Is there any way I can get custom shaped masks working in IE (preferably IE7 and older)?

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve custom-shaped masks in IE?

Comment: Wait, maybe it works when you add this to your head tag: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">`